# Why my pc usb discharge my smartphone?

Tags: usb, lg

When i'm using regular cable to my smartphone connecting to the electric in my house it's charging the smartphone fine. My smartphone is lg g3.

But when i'm connecting my smartphone to my pc usb and i tried two cables i see the percentages on  my smartphone getting down. I see the charging sign on my smartphone like it's charging but instead the percentages getting down until my smartphone is shut down. Then i need to go to my other room and charge it from the wall again.

What could be the reason on the pc it's not only that it's not chraging but also discharing ? Strange. It's not the cable tried two already, I guess it's something with my pc usb but what could it be ?

My pc: intel i7 2.67ghz and 6gb ram windows 8.1 pro 64bit

Comment: You're probably using high resistance USB cables or your USB port is not supplying the proper power. Try with other USB ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the your PCs USB host controller, you computer might only be able to output 250mA of current. Another possibility is outdated usb drivers. If if is charging with the wall adapter, it is likely you have a USB host controller that can't output 2A of current like your wall adapter does. Your best bet is to try all of your USB ports, and try to update your computers drivers.